# Seaborn: markers are not showing up

Tags: python, seaborn, scatter-plot, markers

Using the code found [here](https://medium.com/geekculture/svm-classification-with-sklearn-svm-svc-how-to-plot-a-decision-boundary-with-margins-in-2d-space-7232cb3962c0), i am trying to change the `sns.scatterplot` markers, but can't make it work. Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import random
n = 15
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=20, n_features=2,
                           n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=n)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                   test_size=0.3, stratify=y,
                                   random_state=32)

svc_model = SVC(kernel='linear', random_state=32)
svc_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))

sns.scatterplot(x=X_train[:, 0], 
                y=X_train[:, 1], 
                hue=y_train,
                markers = ['.','+']);

w = svc_model.coef_[0]
b = svc_model.intercept_[0]
x_points = np.linspace(-2, 2)
y_points = -(w[0] / w[1]) * x_points - b / w[1]
plt.plot(x_points, y_points, c='r')
plt.ylabel(r'$x_2$', usetex = True, fontsize = 15, rotation = 0)
plt.xlabel(r'$x_1$', usetex = True, fontsize = 15)
```

I run that script, but the markers doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markers will showing up by adding `style` argument :

```
sns.scatterplot(x=X_train[:, 0],
                y=X_train[:, 1],
                hue=y_train,
                style=y_train,
                markers=['o', 'P'])
```

Note that not all combinations of markers are permitted. Reference: [Filled and line art markers cannot be mixed](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1624)

Output:

[image: Out]